# gemfileのようにyumでインストールするパッケージを管理する方法

Tags: centos

rubyのgemはGemfileがあればプロジェクトごとに必要なパッケージを記録しておくことが出来ますが、
yumにはそのようなものはないのでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

質問の意図と合ってるかわかりませんが Yum （というか rpm）でパッケージを作る際に依存関係をパッケージに持たせることができます。

例えば yum の依存関係は 次のように確認できます。

```
# rpm -qR yum
/usr/bin/python
config(yum) = 3.2.29-69.el6.centos
pygpgme
python >= 2.4
python(abi) = 2.6
python-iniparse
python-sqlite
python-urlgrabber >= 3.9.0-8
rpm >= 0:4.4.2
rpm-python
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PartialHardlinkSets) <= 4.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(VersionedDependencies) <= 3.0.3-1
yum-metadata-parser >= 1.1.0
yum-plugin-fastestmirror
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
```

RPMを作成する際、`spec` ファイルというものを作成しますが その中で依存関係を記述することができます。`Requires` はインストールに必用なパッケージを、`BuildRequires` にはビルド時に必用なパッケージを書きます。

```
Requires: bash
BuildRequires: autoconf automake gzip
```